# Debugging Developer Fabric Issues - Service Not Starting Web Components

Tags: debugging, azure

I am trying to get the Azure SDK up and running on my dev PC and have been having some issues.

I have installed the SDK, tools for VS and am trying to run the samples. Every time I try to run the samples the Development Storage service starts and then the Developer Fabric tries to start. This is where is stops. The Developer Fabric cannot run any websites for whatever reason.

I have followed their checklist for setting up the system and there is not Event messages. I am running under Vista Home Premium with IIS 7 installed.

If you have any suggestions I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After becoming supremely frustrated with this issue I posted it as the following [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=387883) issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem is a little deeper than simply Azure not working on my computer.

In order to natively debug IIS apps using windows vista (configured under the project settings) you need to have windows authentication enabled for IIS. This feature cannot be installed let alone enabled under Vista Home Premium under the guise of what home user would want such a feature.

For the average VS 2005 user this is okay there is a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;937523) but for me and my fancy VS 2008 SP1 there is no solution.